# trying to interact with Python script from JMP

Tags: python, sas

I'have got a python script that was generated from JMP (SAS software),it basically include a formula with 2 parameters, and I want to interact with that formula using a web-service (another software will provide the parameter and will get the result), the issue I'm having is that the syntax looks odd to me, can understand how the program expect to get the parameters ? will appreciate expatiation
attached the script
2 parameters : "EXISTS LASER DRILL"= YES/NO , DESIGN LAYERS"= float

from **future** import division
import jmp_score as jmp
from math import *
import numpy as np

""" ==================================================================
Copyright(C) 2018 SAS Institute Inc.All rights reserved.

Notice:
The following permissions are granted provided that the
above copyright and this notice appear in the score code and
any related documentation. Permission to copy, modify
and distribute the score code generated using
JMP(R) software is limited to customers of SAS Institute Inc. ("SAS")
and successive third parties, all without any warranty, express or
implied, or any other obligation by SAS. SAS and all other SAS
Institute Inc. product and service names are registered
trademarks or trademarks of SAS Institute Inc. in the USA
and other countries. Except as contained in this notice,
the name of the SAS Institute Inc. and JMP shall not be used in
the advertising or promotion of products or services without
prior written authorization from SAS Institute Inc.
================================================================== """

""" Python code generated by JMP v15.0.0 """

def getModelMetadata():
return {"creator": u"Formula Editor", "modelName": u"", "predicted": u"", "table": u"NEW JMP Pricing 30 RIGID SHORT", "version": u"15.0.0", "timestamp": u"2020-08-30T10:46:03Z"}

def getInputMetadata():
return {
u"DESIGN LAYERS": "float",
u"EXISTS LASER DRILL": "str"
}

def getOutputMetadata():
return {
u"Add": "float"
}

def score(indata, outdata):
_temp_0 = np.nan

```
if (indata[u"EXISTS LASER DRILL"] == u"NO"):
    _temp_0 = -130.203324304508
elif (indata[u"EXISTS LASER DRILL"] == u"YES"):
    _temp_0 = 130.203324304508
else:
    _temp_0 = 2 #np.nan
outdata[u"Add"] = 358.593374276362 + 26.8517927560789 * indata[u"DESIGN LAYERS"] + _temp_0

return outdata[u"Add"]
```